# Return text/html on exceptions

Tags: python, exception, flask

I was trying to modify the code example [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/apierrors/) but it seems that jsonify is making it hard... I did the following without jsonify:

```
@app.errorhandler(InvalidUsage)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = error.to_dict()
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response
```

Originally, the third line was like:

```
response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
```

How can I make this work? I don't want to use JSON. Only text/html

Comment: what is not working here ? Your question is not very clear.  What are you expecting to see ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: I get this `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'`

Comment: I expect to see the `message` and `status_code` but I want the Content-Type to be text/html and not application/json

Answer (score 0):

Well, I presume that error.to_dict() returns a dict, which wouldn't have a status code attribute (it's just a regular old dict). You might try this instead:

```
@app.errorhandler(InvalidUsage)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = error.to_dict()
    response["status_code"] = error.status_code
    return response
```

That said, it seems odd that the dictionary wouldn't already have the error code in it. Maybe a bit more detail on what what you are trying to accomplish would help? If you don't call the second-to-last line, and just return response, what do you see?

Comment: Running the code as you suggested returns `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. If I don't cal the second-to-last line it returns the same. What I'm trying to accomplish is exactly the same as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/apierrors/) but without the jsonify, since I don't want the content type to be json

Comment: Can you please post the entire error you are seeing, including the stack trace? I don't know if that TypeError is coming from my code, or if your code is running into an error later on because now it actually finishes executing the error handler.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the jsonify() call? What are you trying to accomplish by doing so? That function fundamentally alters the structure of the error in a way that looks like it is necessary for Flask to do its thing. Do you have something that processes the return value of handle_invalid_usage()? If not, then Flask is probably expecting a jsonified() object to be returned.